# Hiding an endpoint/request type in swagger documentation: AWS Api Gateway, Swagger-UI or another approach?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, swagger-ui

So our team has a problem.

Before that, a little background knowledge. We have a customer facing API that has an accompanying API documentation page. This documentation page is a stand alone application that fetches API documentation from AWS using a AWS SDK. When ever we make changes to said API we update a yaml file and deploy with the following commands

`aws apigateway put-rest-api --rest-api-id XXXXXX --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --mode merge --body 'file://Api.yaml'`

`aws apigateway create-deployment --rest-api XXXXXX --stage-name foostage`

`aws apigateway update-stage --stage-name foostage --rest-api-id XXXXXX --patch-operations "op=replace,path=/documentationVersion,value=$current_version"` where `$current_version` is the version deployed in the first step

I believe the first command updates the definition of our rest api using the `Api.yaml`, second command deploys the latest version of the API to the API Gateway, and the last command is to deploy the `$current_version`, version which was created by the `put-rest-api` command,  documentation to the specified stage.

As stated earlier, our documentation application reaches out to AWS to fetch the documentation and then we use [swagger-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui) to render the swagger documentation.

Back to the problem. We have one endpoint(could have more in the future) that needs to be hidden from documentation but still needs to be included in the API Gateway and be callable. I am wondering what the best way to do this is? Is there a feature in the swagger-ui component or a way to omit an endpoint in the documentation? My current approach is brute force, removing the endpoint from the json we feed to swagger-ui component. Wondering if there are other approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up omitting the endpoint in the front-end layer where we pull the documentation from AWS and then filter the documentation and omit the endpoint before setting the documentation as part of the swagger-ui plugin implementation. From what I could gather, there is no current clean way to omit endpoints via the swagger-ui or AWS.